# How to make CheckButton work like a RadioButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, radio-button, devexpress

Using Devexpress CheckButtons, I want to make them function like Radiobuttons.

Below is part of my code, which I wrote for all 4 checkbuttons, which means it will have to be multiplied along with multiplication of lines of code, which is not feasible approach.

```
private void cb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cb2.checked = false;
        cb3.checked = false;
        cb4.checked = false;
    }
```

I assume there is much shorter way to get other checkbuttons unchecked when I press on one of them.

Comment: Loop through a collection of the buttons, determining which was clicked (`sender` I believe?) and make the rest false. Also, this is more of a job for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DevExpress `CheckButton` class there are [`CheckButton.GroupIndex`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsCheckButton_GroupIndextopic) property. If you set this property for several `CheckButton` controls to the same non-negative value, then this controls will be combined into one logical group in witch only one button can be checked at one time, so there are no need to make something like what you done in your code.
Here is example:

```
var form = new Form();

for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
{
    var cb = new CheckButton()
    {
        Left = 10,
        Top = 10 + index * 20,
        Text = "CheckButton" + index,
        GroupIndex = 0 //<= the same group for each CheckButton
    };

    form.Controls.Add(cb);
}

form.Show();
```

Comment: does this have to be written in class ?

Comment: @oljko What are you talking about? If you are talking about example, then this example is for testing purpose, so you can simply add some button into your form and write this example in the button click event hanlder. If you are talking about `GroupIndex` property, then this property is available in your designer, so you can set the value of this property directly there.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the same event handler to each of the buttons, then you only need the one method:

```
// Create the checkboxes
CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox();
CheckBox cb3 = new CheckBox();
CheckBox cb4 = new CheckBox();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Positioning
    cb1.Left = 10;
    cb2.Left = 10;
    cb3.Left = 10;
    cb4.Left = 10;
    cb1.Top = 10;
    cb2.Top = 30;
    cb3.Top = 50;
    cb4.Top = 70;

    // IMPORTANT BIT - Assign even handlers
    cb1.Click += new EventHandler(CbClick);
    cb2.Click += new EventHandler(CbClick);
    cb3.Click += new EventHandler(CbClick);
    cb4.Click += new EventHandler(CbClick);

    // Add to form
    this.Controls.Add(cb1);
    this.Controls.Add(cb2);
    this.Controls.Add(cb3);
    this.Controls.Add(cb4);
}

private void CbClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Uncheck all
    cb1.Checked = false;
    cb2.Checked = false;
    cb3.Checked = false;
    cb4.Checked = false;

    // Check the one that was clicked
    (sender as CheckBox).Checked = true;
}
```

The example seems long because it is complete, but really you only need the event handlers and the method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
private void cb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cb1.checked = false;
        cb2.checked = false;
        cb3.checked = false;
        cb4.checked = false;
        (sender as CheckBox).checked = true;
    }
```

And assign this method to all Checkboxes OnClick Event.

Comment: This will not make it any shorter :)